# Error estimation for numeric quadrature on an $n$-simplex

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

Suppose I have a sufficiently nice function from a simplex $S$ with vertices $(v_0,\dots,v_n)$ to $\mathbb R$, call it $f$. I want to estimate the error when approximating the integral
$$\int_S d^nxf(x)$$
via the generalized trapezoid rule
$$\frac{1}{(n+1)!}\det
\begin{pmatrix} v_0&\cdots&v_n\\\ 1&\cdots&1\end{pmatrix}\sum\limits_{i=0}^n f(v_i).$$

Wikipedia gives a bound for the $n=1$ case [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule), but I tried quite a bit and the derivation doesn't seem to generalize well. I need suggestions on strategies to estimate the error. A loose bound would be enough, all I need is to understand on what power of the volume, or equivalently what orders of derivatives of $f$ the error scales with.

Comment: Also posted to [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/431214/error-estimation-for-numeric-quadrature-on-an-n-simplex).

Answer (score 1):

I have been working for a while in a similar setting with the same goal: to establish the error bounds for quadratures on $S$.

My approach is constructive, in the sense that I do not count with the general theory as you will see. Instead, I tackle quadrature by quadrature.

Let me consider the case $n=2$ for simplicity, a two-dimensional triangle (I have been able to show that this approach works for $n\leq 4$). Without loss of generality (?) consider the vertices $v_1=(0,0)$, $v_2=(1,0)$, and $v_3=(1,1)$.

The relevant integral is

$$\int_S d^2x\,f(x)\ =\ \int_0^1\int_0^{x_1}f(x_1,x_2)\,dx_2dx_2.$$
In turn, the relevant quadrature reads
$$Q\ =\ \frac{1}{6}f(0,0)\ +\ \frac{1}{6}f(1,0)\ +\ \frac{1}{6}f(1,1)\ .$$
It is straight forward to check that $Q$ integrates exactly polynomials of the form $t_1^\alpha t_2^\beta$ with integers $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that $\alpha+\beta\leq 1$.

To simplify calculations, as you will see, it is convenient to consider the following change of variables:

$$s_1=x_1,\qquad  s_2=\frac{x_2}{x_1}.$$

This change of variables maps the triangle into a square of unit length. Thus,

$$\int_S d^2x\,f(x)\ =\ \int_0^1\int_0^{1}s_1f(s_1,s_1s_2)\,ds_2ds_1.$$
Now integrating by parts twice the outer weighted integral leads to

$$ \int_0^1\int_0^{1}s_1f(s_1,s_1s_2)=-a_1F(0)+\left(a_1+\frac{1}{2}\right)F(1)+a_2F'(0)-\left(a_1+a_2+\frac{1}{6}\right)F'(1)+\int_0^1\left(\frac{s_1^3}{6}+a_1s_1+a_2\right)F''(s_1)\,ds_1$$
where
$$F(s_1):=\int_0^1f(s_1,s_1s_2)\,ds_2\ ,$$
meanwhile $a_1$ and $a_2$ are constants of integration. Note that
$$F(0)=f(0,0)\ ,\qquad F(1)=\int_0^1f(1,s_2)\,ds_2\ .$$
Using again two integration by parts, rewrite $F(1)$ as follows

$$F(1)\ =\ -b_1f(h,0)+(b_1+1)f(h,h)+\int_0^1\left(\frac{s_2^2}{2}+b_2s_2+b_2\right)\left(\frac{\partial^2 f(1,s2)}{\partial s_2^2}\right)\,ds_2+b_2\frac{\partial f(1,0)}{\partial s_2}-\left(b_1+b_2+\frac{1}{2}\right)\frac{\partial f(1,1)}{\partial s_2}$$

were $b_1$ and $b_2$ are constants of integration. We set the value of constants $a's$ and $b's$ in such a way that the quadrature $Q$ is reproduced. Thus, there is only one choice, which is

$$a_1=-\frac{1}{6}\ ,\qquad a_2=0\ ,\qquad b_1=-\frac{1}{2}\ ,\qquad b_2=0\ .$$

In addition, this choice kills any undesired boundary terms involving derivatives. As a result, one establishes that

\begin{align}\int_0^1\int_0^{1}s_1f(s_1,s_1s_2)\,ds_2ds_1\ =&\ Q +\frac{1}{3}\int_0^1\frac{s_2}{2}(s_2-1)\left(\frac{\partial^2f(1,s_2)}{\partial s_2^2 }\right)\,ds_2\\
&+\frac{1}{6}\int_0^1\int_0^1s_1(s_1^2-1)\left(s_2^2\frac{\partial^2 f(s_1,s_1s_2)}{\partial s_2^2}+2s_2\frac{\partial^2 f(s_1,s_1s_2)}{\partial s_1\partial s_2}+\frac{\partial^2 f(s_1,s_1s_2)}{\partial s_1^2}\right)\,ds_1ds_2\ .
\end{align}
From the previous formula you can easily extract the ***exact*** expression for the error, which is easily bounded to obtain error bounds. Rewriting expressions in the original variables can be useful to see the estructure of the error. However, the structure is clear, since $Q$ integrates exactly $t_1^\alpha t_2^\beta$ ($\alpha$ and $\beta$ as before), the error should involve derivatives that annihilates this polynomial (just as it can seen from the above result).

If you establish the order of your trapezoidal-like quadrature, guessing the derivatives involved in the error is feasible.

In any case, I hope it may be useful.